# Is it okey to start link building before my site get indexed?

Tags: seo, backlinks

Self explanatory question. If you have a fresh new site which is not yet indexed by google. Is it okey to start with link building or i should wait to google index my site?

Comment: For those interested, I am maintaining a page to create links efficiently (http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-build-backlinks-efficiently.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course. In fact it can help you get indexed as Google will follow those links to your site. Also, if you can get quality links to your pages, it will encourage Google to index your pages quicker and more frequently.

Comment: +1, with one little comment. Make sure the content is all in there. Because, if you happen to get a link with a lot of juice, Google will index your site quickly, and might index it with missing or temporary content.